# Convert.ToInt32 gives me abnormal results

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am tasked with the project of converting a program coded in C for the JAM run-time environment.  I am trying to copy one of the methods over but C# is doing the oddest things with it.  Let me show you.

I have three strings:

```
string box_fld_inp_lth = "001212912000003510112691610166010";
string box_fld_inp_lt_pos = "003345606900000251020215921651035510200";
string box_fld_inp_rt_pos = "004456688000000491920326429801950560200";
```

If I have an int like this

```
Int32 x = 1;
```

Then I expect `box_fld_inp_lth[x]` to be equal to 0.  Right?
But this statement `Console.WriteLine(box_fld_inp_lth[x])` evaluates to true.
This line `Console.WriteLine(box_fld_inp_lth[x])` brings back zero.
So shouldn't `0 > 0` return false?

I believe I am going crazy because `Convert.ToInt32(box_fld_inp_lth[x])` returns 48?

Why does this happen?  I believe that box_fld_inp_lth at position 1 is a zero, yet Convert.ToInt32 thinks differently.  Why?

Comment: Yep.  chars are not ints.  I just figured that out. :P

Answer (score 2):

What you consider abnormal is only the limitation of what you know

```
Convert.ToInt32(char)
```

will return the ASCII value of that character. e.g.

```
Convert.ToInt32('1')
```

will return 49.

whereas

```
Convert.ToInt32("1")
```

will return 1.

This is how it is implemented and is considered to be normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe I am going crazy because Convert.ToInt32(box_fld_inp_lth[x]) returns 48?

`box_fld_inp_lth[x]` is a `char` and `Convert.ToInt32` returns the ascii code of `0`. To get the integer value do `Convert.ToInt32(box_fld_inp_lth[x].ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

Indexing into a `string` returns a `char`. When you do `Convert.ToInt32` on a charm all it does

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static int ToInt32(char value)
{
    return value;
}
```

In other words, it just gives you the numeric value (some might say 'ASCII' value) of character back.

Only if you're dealing with `string`s does the code really go into the whole `Parse` thing like you want it to.